# Can you add ENV VAR to docker compose up command

Tags: environment-variables, docker-compose

I need to define an env var in docker compose (v2).
Now I just have something like:

```
environment:
- SERVERNAME=192.168.xx.xx
```

But I don't really like this approach. People need to modifiy the compose file. Is there way that I can do this more dynamic. Something like:

```
docker-compose up --env SERVERNAME=192.168.xx.xx
```

What is the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not possible but the most close solution can be pass it in a env file

From de docker [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env_file-configuration-option):

> You can pass multiple environment variables from an external file through to a service’s containers with the ‘env_file’ option.

So you can create a env file with the variable, for example server.env, and reference it in the docker-composer.yml

```
env_file:
  - server.env
```

Or you can create a .env file in the folder

```
$ cat .env
SERVERNAME=192.168.xx.xx
```

And change your config with:

```
environment:
  - SERVERNAME=${SERVERNAME}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do it with `-e "SERVERNAME=192.168.1.1" -e "SOMETHING=bla"` syntax.

Or use something like Hashicorp's Vault.

Comment: `docker-compose up --build -d  -e SERVERNAME="192.168.10.xxx"` or `docker-compose  -e SERVERNAME="192.168.10.10" up` seems not to work..